# Extract shortcode content from another post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a shortcode [Mark] which only used as a marker for texts. And another shortcode [MarkExt] for extracting content of Marker based on the post id.

```
[Mark label="mrk"]Some text here[/Mark]
```

What I need to do is that when I invoke

```
[MarkExt label="mrk" id=10]
```

is to get the text that is enclosed by [Mark] of label mrk specified in the post id.
How can I get the [Mark ] content?

EDIT:  Apologies on incomplete post . What I've done so far was

For [Mark]

```
    function mark_shortcode($atts,$content = null){

                return $content;
        }

add_shortcode( 'Mark', 'mark_shortcode' );
```

And for [MarkExt]

```
function extract_shortcode($atts,$content = null){

            $label = $atts['label'];
            $pid = $atts['id'];

}
add_shortcode( 'MarkExt', 'extract_shortcode' );
```

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you are stuck on something *specific*, please update your question with the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to **functions.php** or plugin file.

```
    function mark_caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
        //$content is Some text here
        return   $content;
    }
    global $mark_content;
    $mark_content = add_shortcode( 'mark', 'mark_caption_shortcode' );


function extract_shortcode($atts,$content = null){
            global $mark_content;
           //here you will get content 
            $label = $atts['label'];
            $pid = $atts['id'];

}
add_shortcode( 'MarkExt', 'extract_shortcode' );
```

Comment: I can get the contents from [Mark] but how can I get its content when I call [MarkExt] ?

Comment: I have doubt about your question. I think, you want content of Mark shortcode for m Markext , right ?

Comment: Hmm I dont seem to get it. I mightve gotten it wrong but I didn't get any contents.